# Error with BQ command line tool: Cannot start a job without a project id

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having issues with the BQ-Command line tool.
Specifically when trying to query a dataset/table, whether one the public datasets or my own I get the error:

BigQuery error in query operation: Cannot start a job without a project id.

I have a project id set as default as per the attached screen shot.
Any help you could give would be appreciated. :-)

Thanks

> BigQuery> ls
>           projectId          friendlyName
>
> ---
>
> ```
> de********nts          De********ing
> ```
>
> BigQuery> query 'select count(*) from publicdata:samples.shakespeare'
>   BigQuery error in query operation: Cannot start a job without a project id.
>   BigQuery> show publicdata:samples.shakespeare
>   Table publicdata:samples.shakespeare
>
> Last modified                  Schema                 Total Rows   Total Bytes   Expiration
>
> ---
>
> 22 Oct 07:27:07   |- word: string (required)           164656       6432064
>                       |- word_count: integer (required)
>                       |- corpus: string (required)
>                       |- corpus_date: integer (required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure gcloud command-line tool first:

```
gcloud config set project 'yourProjectId'
```

This project [is billed](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query#projectId) for querying not public data.

Then you can run your query:

```
bq query 'select count(*) from publicdata:samples.shakespeare'
```

Comment: you can also can try
`bq --project=<you_project> query "select count(*) from [publicdata:samples.shakespeare]"`